# Replace text but not if contain specific characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In JavaScript, I am using the below code to replace text that matches a certain string. The replacement wraps the string like this: `"A(hello)"`. It works great but if there are two strings that are the same, for example: `"Hello hi Hello"`, only the first one will get marked and if I am trying twice, it will get marked double, like this: `"A(A(Hello)) Hi Hello"`.

A solution to this could be to not replace a word if it contains `"A("` or is between `"A("` and `")"`; both would work.

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Note: I cant use **replaceAll** because if there is already a word that is replaced and a new word is added, then the first one will be overwritten. Therefore I need a solution like above. For example,If I have a string saying "Hello hi", and I mark Hello, it will say "A(Hello) hi", but if I then add Hello again to the text and replace it, it will look like this: `A(A(Hello)) hi A(Hello)`.

Here is what I got so far:

```js
let text = "Hello hi Hello!"
let selection = "Hello"
let A = `A(${selection})`
let addWoman = text.replace(selection, A)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion in your pattern that fails the match if we `A(` before full word `Hello`:

```
(?<!A\()\bHello\b
```

And replace it with `A($&)`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZNeNN/1)

**Code:**

```js
let text = "Hello hi Hello!";
let selection = "Hello";
let A = `A(${selection})`;
let re = new RegExp(`(?<!A\\()\\b${selection}\\b`, "g");
let addWoman = text.replace(re, A);

console.log(addWoman);

console.log(addWoman.replace(re, A));
```

Answer (score 1):

> A solution to this could be to not replace a word if it contains "A(" or is between "A(" and ")"; both would work.

**To avoid re-matching `selection` inside a `A(...)` string**, you can match `A(...)` and capture it into a group so as to know if the group matched, it should be kept, else, match the word of your choice:

```js
let text = "Hello hi Hello!"
let selection = "Hello"
let A = `A(${selection})`
const rx = new RegExp(String.raw`(A\([^()]*\))|${selection.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}`, 'g')
let addWoman = text.replace(rx, (x,y) =>  y || A)
console.log(addWoman);
// Replacing the second time does not modify the string:
console.log(addWoman.replace(rx, (x,y) =>  y || A))
```

The regex will look like `/(A\([^()]*\))|Hello/g`, it matches

- `(A\([^()]*\))` - Group 1: `A` and then `(` followed with zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `Hello` - a `Hello` string.